# Fastest way to group elements of a list of integers by their sign?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of non-zero integers and I want to change the list into nested lists (=groups) in which each group contains consecutive integers of the list which has the same sign.

I've done this with the following code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, 7, 8, -9, 10, -11, 12]
groups = [[]]
for (i, x) in enumerate(a):
    if x ^ a[i - 1] < 0:
        groups.append([x])
    else:
        groups[-1].append(x)
```

Now, my question is that is there a faster way to do this? Or what is the fastest way?

Comment: What other ways have you tried?  Show your timing results, at least against the "obvious" way: remember that checking the sign bit is *very* fast.  Why is speed important to the application?  Unless you're doing this for very large sets, you already destroyed your turnaround time by stopping to write this posting.  Also, it appears that readability is not a concern -- this makes me *seriously* question your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seem like itertools.groupby is what you are looking for.

```
import itertools
a = [1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, 7, 8, -9, 10, -11, 12]

c = [list(group) for key,group in itertools.groupby(a, lambda x: x>0)]
print(c)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [-4, -5, -6], [7, 8], [-9], [10], [-11], [12]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is for:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, 7, 8, -9, 10, -11, 12]

[list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x > 0)]
# [[1, 2, 3], [-4, -5, -6], [7, 8], [-9], [10], [-11], [12]]
```

It is *very* efficient for this sort of thing.